# How to count unique minimums?

Tags: mysql, subquery, mariadb

I have a simple query but I am unable to think of a way doing this without a sloppy subquery.

I just need to count new players. I should have this information available as I have a large table full of every seasonal data.

I am currently doing a double group by to first make sure the data is unique, and then count the minimum value of season column to know how many players first started in that season.

```
SELECT 
A.MinSeason AS Season,
count(A.MinSeason) AS NewPlayers
FROM(
    SELECT 
    min(season) as MinSeason
    FROM seasonunion
    WHERE `Games Played` >= 10
    GROUP by `Pilot Name`
)AS A
GROUP BY Season
```

Is there a better way to do this rather than two GROUP BY?

Comment: In the absence of analytic functions (which is the case for MySQL), your current approach looks fine to me.

Comment: Aren't `COUNT` and `MIN` analytic?  The query seems _necessarily_ complex.